# PHP oci_bind_by_name binding function return parameter with -1 not working

Tags: php, oracle, codeigniter-3, oci8

I was trying to bind `$result` variable for a PL/SQL stored function but
it does not work if I bind `$result` variable as

```
oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':result', $result, -1);
```

and gives error Message as :

> oci_execute(): ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small

Also it work for if statement as :

```
oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':result', $result, 1000);
```

But My PL/SQL stored function return large number of data so i want to use maximum lenght as -1.

Reference form : 
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.oci-bind-by-name.php

1) maxlength
Sets the maximum length for the data. If you set it to -1, this function will use the current length of variable to set the maximum length. In this case the variable must exist and contain data when oci_bind_by_name() is called.

2) Example #10 Binding for a PL/SQL stored function.

```
$sql = 'BEGIN :result := QUERY(:parameters); END;';      
$stmt = oci_parse($this->oracle_db->conn_id,$sql);   
oci_bind_by_name($stmt,':parameters',$parameters);   
oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':result', $result, -1);   
oci_execute($stmt);   
oci_free_statement($stmt);   
oci_close($this->oracle_db->conn_id);
```

Error Message:

> oci_execute(): ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify a length so OCI8 knows how much memory to allocate before it calls the database.  Otherwise you are relying on `$result` having a value before you call `oci_execute()`; the length of `$result` *before* calling `oci_execute()` would be maximum size allowed to be returned.  I'd always recommend passing a size to `oci_bind_by_name()` so there are no nasty surprise truncations.

Comment: Thanks Christopher really appreciate your answer :) Also when i try to bind $result with large size of data like 35k its returning me warning message as oci_execute(): ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error. so will this be a variable binding size issue or this will be PL/SQL stored function code issue.

Comment: 4K or 32K (in newer DBs) tend to be magic limits for data transfers between PHP & the DB.  You may want to look at using a LOB, see "LOBs and PL/SQL procedures" on p 237 of http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/php/underground-php-oracle-manual-098250.html

Comment: Thanks Christopher for your valuable solution :)